# bash, detecting mp4 files

Tags: linux, bash

```
if [ -f *.mp4 ]; then
        for file in *.mp4; do 
                ffmpeg2theora -v 8 --nometadata  "$file"
                rm -f "$file"
        done 
fi

if [ -f *.avi ]; then
        for file in *.avi; do
                ffmpeg2theora -v 8 --nometadata  "$file"
                rm -f "$file"
        done
fi
```

I can't figure out why `if [ -f *.mp4 ]; then` is not detecting mp4 files, i use this method it to find .avi, .epub, .chm and some other extensions and it works perfectly. I wonder me if it is because of the `4`. i also tried by doing `if [ -f *."mp4" ]; then` but it didn't work.

I find weird that  `for file in *.mp4; do` detects .mp4 files and `if [ -f *.mp4 ]` not!

Comment: do you get an error message, or does it just skip the block of code for that test? Do your .mp4 filenames have spaces in them? Good luck.

Comment: The block is just skipped, and yes the files names contain spaces but this works for the other extensions. if i replace `if [ -f *.mp4 ]` by `if [ 1 -eq 1 ]` it works fine!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the bash option `nullglob` to allow globs to expand to zero elements. This way, the loop will simply not run if there are no matching files:

```
shopt -s nullglob
for file in *.mp4; do 
    ffmpeg2theora -v 8 --nometadata  "$file" && rm -f "$file" || \
        echo Problem transcoding "$file"
done
```

As for `[ -f *.mp4 ]`, it only works correctly if there is exactly one matching file, because then it expands to `[ -f myfile.mp4 ]`.

If there are no matching files, it may still work (without nullglob) because it ends up checking for a file with an asterisk in the name, which hopefully doesn't exist.

If there are multiple files, it fails, because `[ -f file1.mp4 file2.mp4 file3.mp4 ]` is not valid `test` syntax.

Comment: I edited to prevent file removal on trancoding failure.  In some shells, no matches will try to transcode a non-existent file named '*.mp4', but will just give an error message.

Answer (score 1):

```
if [ -f *.mp4 ]; then
```

There is no expansion inside the test. The test is looking for a file named `*.mp4` which doesn't exist. What you should do it:

```
for i in *.mp4; do
    <do something>
done
```

Here expansion will provide all files with `.mp4` extensions in the present working directory. You can also you `find /path/to/dir -type f -name "*.mp4"` to get your filenames as well. (**note:** this expects `.mp4` files to be present in the directory. If not, `i=*.mp4`. You are safer doing:

```
find /path -type f -name "*.mp4" | while read i; do 
    <do whatever>
done
```

Comment: The problem of simply running `for i in *.mp4; do` is that it produces an error when there is no .mp4 file!

Comment: You are correct. It expects there to be .mp4 files in the directory. If there are none, then `i=*.mp4`. That is why I would do `find /path -type f -name "*.mp4" | while read i; do <whatever>; done`